# how to recall the function when it encounter error in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    client.getAllOffers(null,function(err, resp) {
        if (!err) {
            offer = JSON.parse(resp);
            test1 = offer.allOffersList.length;
            res.send(offer);
            for(var i=0;i<test1;i++) {
                var stmt = "INSERT INTO offers(description,start_time,end_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                connection.query(stmt, [offer.allOffersList[i].description, offer.allOffersList[i].startTime, offer.allOffersList[i].endTime], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err.message;
                    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

In this case i'm having function in getAllOffers in the second line of the code.

If I encounter an error how can I recall the function untill I get the response.

How I will be done?

Comment: I would recommend re-trying upto a certain number of times. If you `re-call the function untill I get the response` then if you never get the response, your code will never terminate

Comment: Furthermore, it's probably very valid that such a "bulk insert" does not even get "retried" at all, and merely returns any error to the user. There's either going to be network errors or a parse error on the response ( which you notably are not trapping ), and either of these really should be immediately reported. Even if this was actually an automated call at regular intervals, then the only "retry" should be on a confirmed network error and nothing else. And even then, **only** for a limited number of times, at which point log the error and escalate for someone to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively by wrapping the `getAllOffers` call in a function. I would recommend putting a limit to the number of retries to prevent an infinite loop.

```js
const getAllOffers = function(callCount) {
  if(callCount < 5) {
    client.getAllOffers(err) => {
      if(!err) {
        console.log('yay!');
      else {
        getAllOffers(++callCount);
      }
    }
  }
}

getAllOffers(0);
```

Comment: Dude. It's an "async" function. You need to wait for each attempt, and it's fail time. So you cant just recursively call like that. It's really really bad as well.